# Please help indentify this rose

Tags: identification, roses

It was pale pink and very fragrant. Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: There are hundreds of species and thousands of cultivars. 1. For an accurate ID it woud be best if you could post a photo of the bush so we can see its particularities. 2. Does it grow in a park, a botanical garden, or private property? 3. Are multiple flowers on a stem, or is there only one? 4. If there are multiple flowers, do they emerge at the same time, or one after another? 5. When does the first flower appear and when does the last? 6. Is this grafted or from cuttings? Sorry for so many questions but they are relevant/necessary. You can edit the question to provide this info. Good luck!

Comment: I think it's a Damask rose

Answer (score 2):

So my best guess is it is an English Rose called "Heritage." This is a beauty and knew I had seen it before.

The Heritage rose is one of the most attractive flowers from the English roses family with it's a classic-cup shaped rose. It's unique among the rose family, because of its near perfect shape of the heritage rose. Heritage rose is also renowned for its light color and fragrance with its gorgeous light pink coloration. Also, the heritage roses spread a pleasant, lemon fragrance.

**Heritage Rose – Additional Info**

- Rose Type - English Rose
- Flower Size - Average diameter of 3.5 inches.
- Blooming period - Summer.
- Growth Type - Shrub Rose
- Sub Type English Musk Hybrid
- Flower Color - light pink
- Fragrance Strength - Very Strong Fragrance
- Flowering - Repeat Flowering
- Disease Resistance - Poor
- Zones - 5-10
- Blossom type - Fully double, up to 40 petals.

Note:  That there are a couple versions of the "Heritage" rose, so be careful when buying it; breeders are tricky.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to know about the bush itself-do the canes arch and are they thin compared to a hybrid tea rose? It looks like either Heritage or Ann Boelyn to me.